# Java : Read user input via JTextField and save the input to a .txt file

Tags: java, textfield, alarm, inout

I am writing a program, which represents a clock, and also has a textfield, which I instantiate with :

```
JTextField tfield = new JTextField();
```

So, I want the user to fill the textfield with a String like `12 34 56` (which should set off the alarm of the clock at that given time).

My main method executes the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    createAndShowGui();
}
```

...where `createAndShowGui()` creates `Panel` and `Frame` (plus `Textfield` and `Buttons`) and calls the other function which I use to display the current time.

[clock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ObyZ.png)

Comment: Hi Skerre - I’m not sure what exactly you are asking. Is something you’ve written not working?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, what is the issue or the intended behavior?

Answer (score 0):

so to clarify my question :

The user should be able to add a String to a Textfield within my frame. The program should write the entered String to a txt.file and also open it when restarted. Thats it !

Greetings !

Answer (score 0):

[JTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) by default allows the user to enter text into it. Its `getText()` method retrieves the text it contains.

Writing to a text file in java is accomplished via one of the `Writer` classes, for example class [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html).

Since *Swing* is event driven, you need to decide which event will call method `getText()` and write that text to a file. I would suggest one of the buttons in your GUI.